# Change column if some regex expression is true with awk or sed

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have a file (lets call it data.csv) similar to this

> "123","456","ud,h-match","moredata"

with many rows in the same format and embedded commas. What I need to do is look at the third column and see if it has an expression. In this case I want to know if the third column has "match" anywhere (which it does). If there is any, then I to replace the whole column to something else like "replaced". So to relate it to the example data.csv file, I would want it to look this.

> "123","456","replaced","moredata"

Ideally, I want the file data.csv itself to be changed (time is of the essence since I have a big file) but it's also fine if you write it to another file.

Edit:

I have tried using awk:

```
awk -F'","' -OFS="," '{if(tolower($3) ~ "stringI'mSearchingFor"){$3="replacement"; print}else print}' file
```

but it dosen't change anything. If I remove the OFS portion then it works but it gets separated by spaces and the columns don't get enclosed by double quotes.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: By replace the whole column, I mean replace the 3rd field in that row completely (so if the field was "jdakakmatch" then i want the field to be "replaced" not "jdakakreplaced"). Sorry for the confusing wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the answer to my question about what you mean by `column`, this may be what you want (uses GNU awk for FPAT):

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]+"' -v OFS=',' '$3~/match/{$3="\"replaced\""} 1' file
"123","456","replaced","moredata"
```

Use `awk -i inplace ...` if you want to do "in place" editing.

With any awk (but slightly more fragile than the above since it leaves the leading/trailing `"` on the first and last fields, and has no `-i inplace`):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""} $3~/match/{$3="replaced"} 1' file
"123","456","replaced","moredata"
```